# Second instance of active-active never received JMS event

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have setup an active-active environment of WSO2 APIM 4.2.0 following the documentation found here: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-an-active-active-deployment/

I have skipped step 5 and 10 (not using analytics).

Both nodes are on different server behind a load balancer. 1 node is on a1, while the other on b1. Both instances can ping themselves and the other. Ports 5672,9611,9711 are open on both machines.

I can see both instances are connected as I stop seeing this log when both machine are up and running:
`No receiver is reachable at URL Endpoint/Endpoints [tcp://wso2am-a1.internal:9611]` or `No receiver is reachable at URL Endpoint/Endpoints [tcp://wso2am-b1.internal:9611]`

I have activated the log to see what event are getting dispatch, but only 1 instance is receiving them, while the other does not react.

When a1 is up but b1 down, a1 is receiving the events.
When b1 is up as well, a1 stop receiving events, b1 is receiving them.
If I stop b1, a1 does not received the events anymore.

I can get the events on both servers if I start them both at the same time, otherwise only the latest server started will get them.

At this point, I don't know if this a configuration problem or or network issue.

a1:

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
provider = "wso2"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
ws_endpoint = "ws://gw.test.com:9099"      #"ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://gw.test.com:8099"    #"wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://gw.test.com"
https_endpoint = "https://gw.test.com"

[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://b1.internal:5672"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://b1.internal:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://b1.internal:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

b1:

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
provider = "wso2"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
ws_endpoint = "ws://gw.test.com:9099"      #"ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://gw.test.com:8099"    #"wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://gw.test.com"
https_endpoint = "https://gw.test.com"

[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://a1.internal:5672"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://a1.internal:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://a1.internal:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

If the configuration is valid, how can I debug the network (what logs need to be enable) so I can find a way to pinpoint where it is coming from?

Comment: Did you put an offset to one of the nodes?

Comment: @RusJaI offset is set to 0 for both instances

Answer (score 0):

Please add a port offset for one of the api manager instances (to avoid port conflicts between multiple instances running on the same host).
You can do it by updating the `deployment.toml` file in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf` directory.

Following is an example :

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
offset=1
```